# Name of BI tools compatible with .NET by which end-user can design their own report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, powerview

I googled a lot but could not get a suitable tool.

I have a .NET application. To make the reporting feature much better, I am trying to find a third party tool for reporting as well as capable to generate the reports as pdf, jpg etc.

The main thing is to design the reports by the end-user as per their needs. I checked Cognos, I found that it gives the output as grid like style but I need in a customized manner too.

I got the below third party tools.

```
Fast Reports
Jreport
Cognos
Combit
```

I need a tool, that is very easy from end-user's prospect.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: To be honest, you have to first define the tool audience - in my experience, very few of end users (of typical LOB apps) would be capable of designing reports (whatever tool it might be). Other users can as such consume these reports (but deigning them - no way). So first fix these audience, their capabilities and their exact needs of customization and then search tool. Also keep an option open for building a simple UI if level of customizations are very simple.

Comment: Yes Vinay, you are absolutely correct, I suggested SSRS first, then went for Cognos. But the client wants to develop the reports from their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want end users to design their own reports on demand, have you tried the new Power View (SQL Serves 2012)?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/Products/PowerView.aspx

Comment: I did not know about that. Its really good.

Comment: The end-user don't have option to access the database. We will provide some views only those they can use. Is it possible from the end-user's side to design the reports from the application?

Comment: This new tool is intended just by that. You can provide some views with limited permissions and fields, you can provide access to a read-only datawarehouse, OLAP cubes, tabular models, ... it's your decision. 

Users will design their reports in a visual web editor (through sharepoint) with a look and feel similar to powerpoint and will save results on a corporative sharepoint report library, or export to a range of usual formats.

It's a very powerfull tool IMHO.

Comment: > *PowerBI* is the latest tool now.